# is there a way to find all the perforce workspaces which are mapping a certain file in the depot?

Tags: mapping, perforce, workspace

I have a file on a perforce depot and when I am updating it with an automated script I want to find all the workspaces mapping the file (with a `p4` command) and send emails to the owners of these workspaces (file is containing the latest view spec of a project and the recipients of the email should get notifications so they can update their view spec too )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761453/how-can-i-query-perforce-for-a-list-of-users-who-have-workspaces-that-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that none of the workspaces you want to look at are using the 'Host' field, you can run:

p4 -c  have

to get a list of all files that are synced on the client.

Note this would first involve you getting a list of all workspaces on the server, by running:

p4 clients

Also this may be quite resource intensive, if your server has a lot of clients that sync a lot of files, so I would recommend using something like the Perforce Review Daemon or Perforce Swarm for code review and notification.

More details about these are available here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html

http://www.perforce.com/collaboration

Hope this helps,
Jen.